# Formula to Count Occurence of Dates between two Other Dates Via Array Formula

Tags: excel

I use this example to illustrate my problem:
[image: excel sheet with my problem]

I can't get *E2* to work. Any ideas?

What I try to do:
I have data showing me a start date (column *from*) and an end date (column *end*). *A2+B2* is one instance, *A3+B3* is another. Cell *C2* holds an event. I want to count in *E2* all instances for which the event is between the start and the end date. I expect *E2* to be 2, but it's 1. I tried to split up the formula by using column *D*, where I calculate the result for each instance separately. That seems to work, i.e. it shows 1 for all instances. But I can't seem to make the array formula in *E2* get to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2>$A$2:$A$3),--($C$2<$B$2:$B$3))
```

[image]

If you really need an array formula, perhaps:

```
=SUM(--($C$2>$A$2:$A$3)*--($C$2<$B$2:$B$3))
```

[image]